# What is this object initialiser pattern called?

Tags: c#

I'm reviewing some code with an object initialisation pattern that I don't recognise - can anyone tell me what this pattern is called (and where to find documentation on usage)?

```
obj.myType = (myVar = new MyType());
```

In case it matters, the specific use-case is as follows;

```
protected MyType myVar;
protected readonly MyComplexType myComplexType;

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)) {
    ...
    myComplexType.myType = (myVar = new MyType());
    ...
}
```

Comment: One instance of this are lazy fields: `get { return fld ?? (fld = new C()); }`. Once you're used to this it's a nice, terse shortcut.

Comment: I would call this pattern "bad code"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's just assigning the same value twice - once to `myVar` and once to `myComplexType.myType`.

It's equivalent to

```
var tmp = new MyType();
myVar = tmp;
myComplexType.myType = tmp;
```

(In some complex cases there can be type conversions going on there, but I don't expect there to be any in this particular case.)

You don't need to use the extra local variable, of course. This code is "somewhat equivalent" but involves reading from `myVar` so isn't *exactly* equivalent, but more likely to be what you'd use:

```
myVar = new MyType();
myComplexType.myType = myVar;
```

There's no specific name for this, and it's *relatively* rare to use the result of an assignment elsewhere in an expression, with the most common example being:

```
string line;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: So then I guess there's no reason to use it?

Comment: @smoksnes: Well it's a shorter way of assigning the same value to two variables... whether you prefer it to the longhand or not is a different matter.

Comment: I favour readability so for a rare pattern like this I have to agree with @smoksnes

Comment: Is C# handling it different to other languages? In most languages, `a = b = c;` is equivalent to `b=c; a=b;`, which makes a difference if `a = c` would be a legal assignment but `a = b` is not (e.g. if `b` has a broader type than `a` and `c`).

Comment: @Holger: No, it sounds like largely C# is the same as the languages you're thinking of. The "equivalent" code here is taking advantage of the fact that we know the type of `myVar`. It's hard to give code that is exactly equivalent in all cases without making the answer really, really confusing.